# Azure Devops self hosted agent with vmss and cloud-init

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, cloud-init

We use AzureDevops for compiling our code, creating helm charts and docker images. My goal is to come up with a solution to make agents more dynamic so that they can scale as the queue increases.

To solve the above issue I am trying to use self-hosted-agents using a virtual machine scale-set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops

The scaleset part works fine but one thing I noticed is that when a ubuntu image is installed it doesn't contain `docker` and `dotnetcore`. After some research I decided to use cloud init to install these dependencies

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true

packages:
 - unzip
 - git
 - wget
 - ca-certificates
 - curl
 - gnupg-agent
 - apt-transport-https
 - software-properties-common
 - powershell
 - azure-cli
 - terraform
 - jq
 - npm
 - docker.io
 - nodejs
 - kubectl
 - dotnet-sdk-5.0

apt:
    preserve_sources_list: true
    sources:
        docker.list:
            source: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $RELEASE stable
            keyid: 9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88
        hashicorp.list:
            source: "deb https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main"
            key: | 
                -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

                mQINBF60TuYBEADLS1MP7XrMlRkn1Y54cb2UclUMH8HkIRfBrhk5Leo9kNZc/2QD
                LmdQbi3UbZkz0uVkHqbFDgV5lAnukCnxgr9BqnL0GJpO78le7gCCbM5bR4rTJ6Ar
                OOtIKf25smGTIpbSwNdj8BOLqiExGFj/9L5X9S5kfq3vtuYt+lmxKkIrEPjSYnFR
                TQ2mTL8RM932GJod/5VJ2+6YvrCjtPu5/rW02H1U2ZHiTtX6ZGnIvv/sprKyFRqT
                x4Ib+o9XwXof/LuxTMpVwIHSzCYanH5hPc7yRGKzIntBS+dDom+h9smx7FTgpHwt
                QRFGLtVoHXqON6nXTLFDkEzxr+fXq/bgB1Kc1TuzvoK601ztQGhhDaEPloKqNWM8
                Ho7JU1RpnoWr5jOFTYiPM9uyCtFNsJmD9mt4K8sQQN7T2inR5Us0o510FqePRFeX
                wOJUMi1CbeYqVHfKQ5cWYujcK8pv3l1a6dSBmFfcdxtwIoA16JzCrgsCeumTDvKu
                hOiTctb28srL/9WwlijUzZy6R2BGBbhP937f2NbMS/rpby7M1WizKeo2tkKVyK+w
                SUWSw6EtFJi7kRSkH7rvy/ysU9I2ma88TyvyOgIz1NRRXYsW7+brgwXnuJraOLaB
                5aiuhlngKpTPvP9CFib7AW2QOXustMZ7pOUREmxgS4kqxo74CuFws163TwARAQAB
                tFFIYXNoaUNvcnAgU2VjdXJpdHkgKEhhc2hpQ29ycCBQYWNrYWdlIFNpZ25pbmcp
                IDxzZWN1cml0eStwYWNrYWdpbmdAaGFzaGljb3JwLmNvbT6JAk4EEwEIADgWIQTo
                oDLglNjrTqGJ0nDaQYyIoyGfewUCXrRO5gIbAwULCQgHAgYVCgkICwIEFgIDAQIe
                AQIXgAAKCRDaQYyIoyGfe6/WD/9dTM/1OSgbvSPpPJOOcn5L1nOKRBJpztr4V0ky
                GoCDakIQ/sykbcuHXP79FGLzrM8zQOsbvVp/Z2lsWBnxkT8KWM+8LZxYToRGdZhr
                huFPHV9df0vAsZGisu4ejHDneHOTO3KqVotkky34jUSjBL7Q8uwXHY9r+5hb452N
                vafN1w0Y1QVhb6JjjwWHR8Rf9qkSIEi6m9o8a1M54yQC2y/Zrs6+4F3zZ4uYfTvz
                MyFfj0P5VmAoaowLSRdb2/JTObu0+zpKN+PjZA8BcnOf/pvqmEz83FIfo6zJLScx
                TVaAwj5Iz/jS04x7EvBuIP3vpgv1R6r+t0qU/7hpu7Oc0dsxhL+C8BpVY26/2hvX
                ozN5eG0ysSwexqwls+bnRgd6KdoHlWFNfbW8RCPKyb/s+tmFqGAY/QmxMkukgnXQ
                WvBoa0Gdv2AFVLYup9tEO1zF4zBPh5oQwAXDNudLTHJ4KmyEwWsOQJUjNB4y4a7j
                iGgK77T4KKXpo7pVDP8Ur+tmNH/d+/YFjxrfJvWt4ypE5dZmFO/FrUMvIGglOLDt
                A+SiQe73IpEebB8PiqNlqJ2NU7artuRxYQVColt+/1puIHwV+h0SnMoUEvYqAtxP
                J/N3JaiytWlesPPFWvhU/JGUAld5coEU2gbYtlenV/YmdjilIBu50sMSPGF5/6gv
                BAA/DbkCDQRetE7mARAA0OH1pn0vdEfSm1kdqIDP3BXBD0BRHNNgGpyXXRRJFaip
                bmpu7jSv3FsvN/NmG3BcLXXLFvwY/eIOr6fxRye+a5FSQEtvBnI1GHNmD5GAVT/H
                KiwrT5e3ReR/FQS7hCXWU4OA2bKmSEdkJ952NhyYeyAKbkOBgbnlEhtWOAdMI7ws
                peHAlHDqfGVOKXDh+FddCUQj/yZ2rblSzFdcC9gtcJSyHWgOQdVAEesEZ16hcZoj
                +6O+6BXOQWOo7EPD7lA9a1qesBkSRcxQn48IVVZ2Qx2P2FtCfF+SFX+HQdqJGl15
                qxE5CXTuJCMmCVnWhvcLW405uF/HmMFXdqGobEDiQsFFQrfpPVOi4T90VkW8P81s
                uPoAlWht1CppNnmhWlvPQsPK/oSMBBOvOEH1EnWJate8yIkveNbqzrE7Xt3sjF6k
                yqXaF+qW8OcDvSH/fgvVd21G10Cm77Z2WaKWvfi221oWj+WrgT8cCYv0AVmaLRMe
                dajuYlPRQ8KaZaESza2eXggOMP5LQs/mQgfHfwSRekSbKg/L6ctp+xrZ0DPj4iIl
                8+H4DxTILopAFWXA1a+uMVp8mV77gA9PyV3nIkrwgaZQ8MdhoKwvN/+SbvhpdzyF
                UekzMP/HOaC6JgAomluwnFCdMDFa3FMCF3QUcIyY556QdoFD7g6033xqV6vL+d8A
                EQEAAYkCNgQYAQgAIBYhBOigMuCU2OtOoYnScNpBjIijIZ97BQJetE7mAhsMAAoJ
                ENpBjIijIZ97lecP+wTgSqhCz3TlUshR8lVrzECueIg3jh3+lY56am9X4MoZ2DAW
                IXKjWKVWO55WPYD15A7+TbDyb4zh55m81LxSpV0CSRN4aPuixosWP4d0l+363D2F
                oudz+QyvoK5J2sKFPMfhdTgGsEYVO/Zbhus5oNi0kjUTD9U7jHWPS3ilvk/g2F+k
                T68lL9+oooleeT+kcBvbKt487JUOwMrkmHqNZdh8qmvMASAuqBcEcqjz96kVEMJY
                bhn2skexKfIncoo/btixzJUbnplpDfibFxUHhvWWdwIv4kl3YnrCKKGSDoJcG1mV
                sQegK4jWVGrqY8MnCI48iotP18ZxyqOycsZvs2jNmFlKwD9s1mrlr97HZ1MYbLWr
                Hq06owH0AzVRM7tzMK7EuHkFLcoa8qh3oijn8O0B7xNOKpTZ2DjajQ/1w8nqmMi5
                Z3Wie6ivKng/7p6c6HDrKjoQYc0/fuh1YnL60JG2Arn1OwdBsLDlzPL+Ro5iNwoJ
                hZ+stxoZT48iAIWonBsLU11Y+MSwWdN1Eh411HTTunrEs6SafMEhnPi7vvUIZhny
                Es0qOM/IUR1I0VtsurSn8aA6Y2Bp73+HuqFLx13/tPKBIUo6D7n/ywUlDCo7wtCw
                aSgXPw6uF+0CyLOQ0haf2j6w1OB8ayEGSkTPER5rImCJf3MGw8IECGrErAd+
                =emKC
                -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        microsoft-azurecli.list:
            source: "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli focal main"
            key: |
                -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
                Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)

                mQENBFYxWIwBCADAKoZhZlJxGNGWzqV+1OG1xiQeoowKhssGAKvd+buXCGISZJwT
                LXZqIcIiLP7pqdcZWtE9bSc7yBY2MalDp9Liu0KekywQ6VVX1T72NPf5Ev6x6DLV
                7aVWsCzUAF+eb7DC9fPuFLEdxmOEYoPjzrQ7cCnSV4JQxAqhU4T6OjbvRazGl3ag
                OeizPXmRljMtUUttHQZnRhtlzkmwIrUivbfFPD+fEoHJ1+uIdfOzZX8/oKHKLe2j
                H632kvsNzJFlROVvGLYAk2WRcLu+RjjggixhwiB+Mu/A8Tf4V6b+YppS44q8EvVr
                M+QvY7LNSOffSO6Slsy9oisGTdfE39nC7pVRABEBAAG0N01pY3Jvc29mdCAoUmVs
                ZWFzZSBzaWduaW5nKSA8Z3Bnc2VjdXJpdHlAbWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbT6JATUEEwEC
                AB8FAlYxWIwCGwMGCwkIBwMCBBUCCAMDFgIBAh4BAheAAAoJEOs+lK2+EinPGpsH
                /32vKy29Hg51H9dfFJMx0/a/F+5vKeCeVqimvyTM04C+XENNuSbYZ3eRPHGHFLqe
                MNGxsfb7C7ZxEeW7J/vSzRgHxm7ZvESisUYRFq2sgkJ+HFERNrqfci45bdhmrUsy
                7SWw9ybxdFOkuQoyKD3tBmiGfONQMlBaOMWdAsic965rvJsd5zYaZZFI1UwTkFXV
                KJt3bp3Ngn1vEYXwijGTa+FXz6GLHueJwF0I7ug34DgUkAFvAs8Hacr2DRYxL5RJ
                XdNgj4Jd2/g6T9InmWT0hASljur+dJnzNiNCkbn9KbX7J/qK1IbR8y560yRmFsU+
                NdCFTW7wY0Fb1fWJ+/KTsC4=
                =J6gs
                -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        microsoft-prod.list:
            source: "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main"
            key: |
                -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
                Version: GnuPG v1.4.7 (GNU/Linux)

                mQENBFYxWIwBCADAKoZhZlJxGNGWzqV+1OG1xiQeoowKhssGAKvd+buXCGISZJwT
                LXZqIcIiLP7pqdcZWtE9bSc7yBY2MalDp9Liu0KekywQ6VVX1T72NPf5Ev6x6DLV
                7aVWsCzUAF+eb7DC9fPuFLEdxmOEYoPjzrQ7cCnSV4JQxAqhU4T6OjbvRazGl3ag
                OeizPXmRljMtUUttHQZnRhtlzkmwIrUivbfFPD+fEoHJ1+uIdfOzZX8/oKHKLe2j
                H632kvsNzJFlROVvGLYAk2WRcLu+RjjggixhwiB+Mu/A8Tf4V6b+YppS44q8EvVr
                M+QvY7LNSOffSO6Slsy9oisGTdfE39nC7pVRABEBAAG0N01pY3Jvc29mdCAoUmVs
                ZWFzZSBzaWduaW5nKSA8Z3Bnc2VjdXJpdHlAbWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbT6JATUEEwEC
                AB8FAlYxWIwCGwMGCwkIBwMCBBUCCAMDFgIBAh4BAheAAAoJEOs+lK2+EinPGpsH
                /32vKy29Hg51H9dfFJMx0/a/F+5vKeCeVqimvyTM04C+XENNuSbYZ3eRPHGHFLqe
                MNGxsfb7C7ZxEeW7J/vSzRgHxm7ZvESisUYRFq2sgkJ+HFERNrqfci45bdhmrUsy
                7SWw9ybxdFOkuQoyKD3tBmiGfONQMlBaOMWdAsic965rvJsd5zYaZZFI1UwTkFXV
                KJt3bp3Ngn1vEYXwijGTa+FXz6GLHueJwF0I7ug34DgUkAFvAs8Hacr2DRYxL5RJ
                XdNgj4Jd2/g6T9InmWT0hASljur+dJnzNiNCkbn9KbX7J/qK1IbR8y560yRmFsU+
                NdCFTW7wY0Fb1fWJ+/KTsC4=
                =J6gs
                -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

# create the docker group
groups:
  - docker

# Install Docker, for production, consider pinning to stable versions
runcmd:
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io unzip wget jq
  - systemctl start docker
  - systemctl enable docker
  # install dotnet
  - wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
  - dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
  - apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod &&  apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1 -y

  - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose 

# Add default auto created user to docker group
system_info:
  default_user:
    groups: [docker]
```

Using the above configuration I noticed two things which I would like to solve

1. More urgently I noticed that as the scale-set scales, it starts accepting jobs even before docker and dotnetcore are installed (runcmd part of the script seems to be working), thus failing the build
2. The items under `packages:` section of the config are not installed

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Build a base image in a shared image gallery that contains your prerequisites.

Comment: Beat me to it - forget about the apparent race condition of the agent showing online before it's completely initialized - by installing docker when the agent starts up, you're slowing down the pool's responsiveness to load. Create a new VM based on that Ubuntu image, add EVERYTHING you want to it, generalize it, create an image, publish to a shared gallery.

Comment: I sloved this by adding `sudo cloud-init status --wait` as the first step in the pipeline.
...
Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77526124/972759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69301685/972759) ... but I might switch to golden images.