# How to wait for full cloud-initialization before VM is marked as running

Tags: azure-devops, rhel, cloud-init

I am currently configuring a virtual machine to work as an agent within Azure (with Ubuntu as image). In which the additional configuration is running through a cloud init file.

In which, among others, I have the below 'fix' within bootcmd and multiple steps within runcmd.

However the machine already gives the state running within the azure portal, while still running the cloud configuration phase (cloud_config_modules). This has as a result pipelines see the machine as ready for usage while not everything is installed/configured yet and breaks.

I tried a couple of things which did not result in the desired effect. After which I stumbled on the following [article/bug](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/issues/1938);

The proposed solution worked, however I switched to a rhel image and it stopped working.
I noticed this image is not using walinuxagent as the solution states but waagent, so I tried to replacing that like the example below without any success.

```
bootcmd:
- mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/waagent.service.d
- echo "[Unit]\nAfter=cloud-final.service" > /etc/systemd/system/waagent.service.d/override.conf
- sed "s/After=multi-user.target//g" /lib/systemd/system/cloud-final.service > /etc/systemd/system/cloud-final.service
- systemctl daemon-reload
```

After this, also tried to set the runcmd steps to the bootcmd steps. This resulted in a boot which took ages and eventually froze.

---

Since I am not that familiar with rhel and Linux overall, I wanted to ask help if anyone might have some suggestions which I can additionally try.

(Apply some other configuration to ensure await on the cloud-final.service within a waagent?)

Comment: did you got the answer to this?

Comment: @PSKP Unfortunately not, switched back to another ubuntu image..

Comment: I was using ARM template deployment. Added Custom Script extension to monitor status. It is working. JFYI. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been proposed by [@brett-holman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7407726/brett-holman)

To block further execution of your Continuous Delivery pipeline (for instance Azure DevOps Pipeline) until cloud-init provisioning is fully completed on instantiating VM you can run this AZ CLI command ([az vm run-command create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-create)):

```
az vm run-command create \
  --run-command-name "awaitCloudInitIsDone" \
  --resource-group "${vmResourceGroup}" \
  --vm-name "${vmName}" \
  --async-execution "false" \
  --run-as-user "${vmAdminUsername}" \
  --run-as-password "${vmAdminPassword}" \
  --timeout-in-seconds 3600 \
  --script "sudo cloud-init status --wait"
```

Answer (score 0):

> However the machine already had the state running, while still running the cloud configuration phase (cloud_config_modules).

Could you please be more specific? Where did you read the machine state?

The reason I ask is that `cloud-init status` will report `status: running` until cloud-init is done running, at which point it will report `status: done`

I what is the purpose of waiting until cloud-init is done? I'm not sure *exactly* what you are expecting to happen, but here are a couple of things that might help.

If you want to execute a script "at the end" of cloud-init initialization, you could put the script directly in `runcmd`, and if you want to wait for cloud-init in an external script you could do `cloud-init status --wait`, which will print a visual indicator and eventually return once cloud-init is complete.

Comment: I appended additional information as to your questions

Comment: I also tried to add cloud-init status --wait within the bootcmd, this resulted in the same situation; Giving status ready within the azure portal and after that running cloud init

Comment: Running cloud-init status --wait inside bootcmd or runcmd will deadlock, since it's waiting on itself. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

On not too old Azure Linux VM images, cloud-init rather than WALinuxAgent acts as the VM provisioner. The VM is marked provisioned by the Azure cloud-init datasource module very early during cloud-init processing ([source](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/main/cloudinit/sources/helpers/azure.py#L867)), before any cloud-init modules configurable with user data. WALinuxAgent is only responsible for provisioning Azure VM extensions. It does not appear to be possible to delay sending the 'VM ready' signal to Azure without modifying the VM image and patching the source code of cloud-init Azure datasource.